# Inline base64 encoded link not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, hyperlink, base64

I have this link:

```
<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x...KJSVFT0YK">PDF</a>
```

In Safari on MacOsX, clicking the link instantly opens the PDF. In Firefox 3.6.2, it doesn't. When I choose Download, it saves it as "u7WYuJME.pdf(2).part", which is a valid PDF file. When I choose "Open with Preview", it downloads it but does not open it. Can I change something so that Firefox opens it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is like that for any data, not only to pdf

See a browser support chart [here](http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/) (the site itself is not related, but it explains your problem)

> **Firefox 3.0+**
>
> Filename is random alphanumeric with
>   ".part" extension
>
> Firefox generates filenames such as a5sZQRsx.zip.part, and Safari isn't much better with just Unknown. Sadly there is no pure Javascript solution to this. However...